# Space Heating with Heat Pump and Ground Source Heat Exchanger Dymola

Tags: model, fluid, modelica, dymola

According the whole year weather data and based on *Buildings.Controls.SetPoints.SupplyReturnTemperatureReset* (assuming working temperatures; supply temp. 30 Celcius and return temp. 25 Celcius) I want to find out how much heat and electrical power is needed from the heat pump (coupled the ground source heat exchanger) in order to keep the working conditions.

Questions:

1. With which component should *SetPointSupplyTemperature* be connected?
2. Do I need *Val2* for the system work?
3. What should be connected with *Modelica_Blocks_Interfaces_RealInput*?

[image: Screenshot of system]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with neither the `Buildings` library nor heating systems, so take my answers with some caution.

1. I assume "Setpoint for supply temperature" refers to the output `TSup` of `Buildings.Controls.SetPoints.SupplyReturnTemperatureReset`, called `TDryBul` in your model (so the unconnected output): I think this should be the temperature of the fluid at the connector `port_b1` of `Buildings.Fluid.HeatPumps.ReciprocatingWaterToWater` indicated by the red pipe in the icon (if that class is actually used, which is uncertain only judging from the icon). This cannot be set directly as far as I can tell. From what I understand you should control the Real-Input `y` of `heaPum` to a value which results in the desired temperature (=`TDryBul`) at `port_b1`. So this could be accomplished using a closed loop control.
2. I don't think so. You have a variable pump `fan1` in your system, which gives you the possibility to control the flow already. Therefore `val2` seems to be redundant and can - if both set a mass flow - even make your system singular (resulting in an error during translation).
3. See (1.). I think it should be connected to the output of a controller (e.g. `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.LimPID` or `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.PI`), to set the the "Modulating signal for compressor frequency", which is limited to a value between zero and one. Having a system that is dimensioned correctly should then result in the correct temperature at the output of `heaPum`.

General notes:

- I'm not sure the system is complete that way it is shown in the screenshot. From what I know, both circuits are closed loops rather than having an open loop for the heating system (which should be the right side of your system).
- Instead of screenshot it is usually very helpful to post the Modelica-Code of your model.